# Javascript input form | display "creating... " and refresh page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Below I have script `js` and form.

```js
$(document).on('submit','#form_create_user',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var fd = new FormData(this);
    var obj = $(this);
    fd.append('course_id', "<?php echo $this->uri->segment(4); ?>");
    obj.find('input[type="submit"]').val("Creating...")
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        data: fd,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (dataofconfirm) {
            // do something with the result
           // obj.find('input[type="submit"]').val("Confirm")
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('home/saveValues/'); ?>",
        data: fd,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (dataofconfirm) {
            // do something with the result
            toastr.success("Success created user.");
            obj.find('input[type="submit"]').val("Confirm")
        }
    });
  })
```

```html
<form action="?" method="post" name="form_create_user" id="form_create_user">
      <input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="test"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Confirm">
</form>
```

When I click on submit form then this script change text on button from "create" to "creating..." and display success action. But now this take about 1sec.

I need extand this script and I need:
display "creating..." for one minute and then return a success action.

**note:** the script run by form I need to set to run immediately, but only return success after a minute and reload the page.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why would you want to purposely prevent the page from being updated for 1 minute? If you're hoping that some action will have been completed on the server before that delay ends, then there are far better ways to do that without wasting the user's time.

Comment: Because our application  instalator from this form take about one minute. If customer enter url before 1 minute, then see white page..

Comment: *"about 1 minute"* - so if it's quicker your user is left waiting pointlessly and if (when!) it's slower, you tell the user it's done but when they try they get an error.  That's not good UX.

Comment: Regardless:  inside your (2nd) ajax `success: function (dataofconfirm) { setTimeout(() => { toastr.success("Success created user."); ... }, 1000 * 60 }`  - generally use the format `1000 * 60` rather than `60000` because a) it's easier to read - is that 60000 or 600000? and b) it's clear that it's 60 seconds as setTimeout is in ms.